# Invalid ReCAPTCHA client id: 0

Tags: angularjs, recaptcha

I have implemented `google reCaptcha` which was working fine. Suddenly I can see below error[image: of recaptcha]

This is how I have implemented using my angular code:

```
<div vc-recaptcha key="web_key" on-create="setRecaptchaId(widgetId)"></div>
```

I tried searching some old threads but no luck.

> Update:

ok, I am getting this error when I add a directive

```
<span class="input-group-addon"
        smilies-selector="chatData.msg"
        smilies-placement="right"
        smilies-title="Smilies"></span>
```

why so ? whats happening actually here ?